# Why does oscilloscope high-resolution mode for acquisition show inconsistent measurements?

Tags: oscilloscope, voltage-measurement, instrumentation, accuracy, precision

Question: Why I get inconsistent measurements from scope specifically in high resolution mode,

i. At cold start higher values are obtained, as time passes measurements drift (gets lesser values)

ii. which would be accurate/actual measurements (before or after) and What could be reasons ?

Here is the description of the scenario.

I am using using Agilent DSO6052A oscilloscope. I have to take precise measurements of 10V peak-peak, with +/-20mv accuracy.

When I try to measure voltage using 'Normal' Acquire mode, I get auto calculated peak-peak values as 10.13-10.19 Vpp.

Problem is that, When I try to use 'High Resolution' Acquire Mode, at cold start of oscilloscope it shows 10.05 Vpp, as time passes (for hours) it slowly reduces to 9.95-9.96 Vpp.
If I let oscilloscope ON for 2-3 hours (in high resolution mode), then probe the signal to take measurements, it shows 9.95-9.96 Vpp. Some times it shows 9.97-9.98 Vpp.

I think, some thing is wrong with scope when used in high resolution mode.

I want to learn from your experience, if any one might have faced this kind of issue.

Looking forward for your answers/suggestions/tips.

Thanks

Comment: How do you know it isn't your voltage source that is changing?

Comment: I know that companies that need precision measurements need NIST traceable standards and half-yearly engineer visits from the manufacturer to make sure their equipment is as accurate as possible. But 0.1V isn't terribly accurate and shouldn't need any of that stuff. Can you try it with more than one voltage source, see if the oscilloscope warming up affects both sources or just the one you are testing? Can you try with the source warm and the scope cold, then with the source cold and the scope warm?

Comment: If you want high resolution measurements you should be using a bench multimeter, or a DAQ, not an oscilloscope. Oscilloscopes are made for bandwidth, not accuracy.

Comment: Don't forget that some measurement devices must be **ON for days** before they can take "samples" with "high precision". High precision laboratories **never switch OFF** their equipment.

Comment: Does it require 3 hours, or is less than 30 minutes sufficient to stabilize the measurement?

Comment: @Aaron, I have used mutliple sources, this 10vpp is an AC signal (Pulse -5, +5), i have also applied a 5V Dc in high resolution it shows same behaviour.

Comment: @user253751  source warm and the scope cold, then with the source cold and the scope warm,  its same as I have discussed.

Comment: "more than minutes" -- was a number missing?

Comment: @TimWilliams, more than 30 minutes, to stabilize the output, at cold start.